# is it possible to make an event listener act as an alarm clock?

Tags: ios

I want my event listener to perform as an alarm clock. The user picks a date and time and the event listener does it at that time. using storyboard

Answer (score 0):

You probably want [UILocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html), as your app could quit or go to background at any moment.